# Automatically generate elasticsearch template

Tags: elasticsearch

How do you create a template when i run elasticsearch for log collection on a container like a docker?
If i try to create a template after elasticsearch, already have indexes created.
So i need to create a template before elasticsearch can work.

In the past, I seem to have configured a template in the config file,
I can not do that now.
i can only create templates in the REST way.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_mapping` to define your index:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

This is a REST call and you could generate the mapping using different methods.